# Transformer connection for active balancer

Tags: cell-balancing, battery-balance

I am currently looking to implement an active balancer based on the LTC3300-1 for a 3-S LiPo array but I am unsure with the transformers, the [datasheet](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/LTC3300-1.pdf) shows how to connect the IC for a 3-S array.

[image]

I have a question with the C6 pin transformer secondary connection, I draw my schematic based on the figure 3 of the datasheet (6-cell active balancer module)

[image]

The secondary terminal with label `UP TO CELL 12`, what does that mean if this schematic is for 6 cells?

Figure 5. (18-cell active balancer) shows the top LTC3300-1 with its secondary connected to the C6 pin (highest voltage pin), so, for my 3-cell application do I need the secondary of the last transformer (transformer 3) connected to the highest voltage pin?

[image]

If that is correct, do I need to have something like this (but for three cells)? (I mean the C6 pin connected to the primary terminal and the secondary terminal?)

[image]

Comment: I think I should connect the last secondary to the C6 terminal, I have been reading the datasheet a lot, please someone could confirm or explain me?

Comment: I'm not sure what your problem is with the transformers (as stated in your opening question). This usually puts people off from making an answer straight away because, it's not really a question and, it carries very little usable information that someone can use to help you. You need to be clearer with what you ask. You should also note that if someone looked at your previous questions, none (since Mar 21st) have received an answer acceptance from you and, this also puts people off helping quite a bit.

Comment: That is true, I now accepted some answers as solution! thank you